# Integrate external live agent chat with Service Cloud Omni Feature

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

Salesforce service cloud has the Omni feature, like introduced in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dC4x8u-UGY) in the Salesforce youtube channel.

How about if we have an existing external chat live agent, and we want to integrate it into Ommni feature.

How can this be achieved? High level design, tips, possible solutions are all welcomed!

I found the [omni channel SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/service_presence_soap_api_intro.htm) and [live agent API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_understanding_resources.htm), but both of which are diffuclt to interpret without given examples.